# how to optimize this sql server update request

Tags: sql, sql-server

I work on sql server, and I want to optimize this request, it takes a lot of time!

```
Update T_Stock
SET 
Flag_Delete = T_Delta.Flag_Delete,
Date_Chgt = T_Delta.Date_Chgt,
Date_Maj = ?
FROM Delta.JDonneesComplementaires_RattPop T_Delta
INNER JOIN stock.JDonneesComplementaires_RattPop T_Stock ON T_Delta.Concat_JDonneesComplementaires_RattPop = T_Stock.Concat_JDonneesComplementaires_RattPop
WHERE Mode_Alim='S'
```

Comment: To which table does the `Mode_Alim` column belong?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen To T_Delta

Answer (score 2):

The following index may speed up the join and `WHERE` filter:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON Delta.JDonneesComplementaires_RattPop
    (Concat_JDonneesComplementaires_RattPop, Mode_Alim);
```

The first component of the index `RattPop` would target the `ON` clause of the join, while the second component `Mode_Alim` would cover the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: It is better to invert the order of the columns in this index. For a nested loops with `JDonneesComplementaires_RattPop` on the inside it doesn't make any difference but for any other join it saves reading unnecessary rows not meeting the `WHERE Mode_Alim='S'` predicate

Comment: @MartinSmith ... and I wouldn't question your suggestion, I was actually going to also suggest that the inverse order might perform better (but I was on a cell phone at the time).